# Does the association between Gringotts and Barclays in fan-fiction originate with JK Rowling?

Tags: harry-potter, fan-fiction

There is a "standard" in Harry Potter fan fiction, that very often, when Goblins of Gringotts need to act in a banking capacity in the Muggle world, they use [Barclay's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barclays) bank (if such a bank is named at all).

This seems consistent enough across authors/years that I started to wonder **if this idea is actually in some way originating in JK Rowling canon**?